# Connect-ExchangeOnline from AWS PowerShell lambda throws PSRemotingTransportException

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to exchange from AWS Powershell Lambda function. The script is working fine locally but throws below error when executed from AWS.

**Powershell script:**

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWSPowerShell.NetCore';ModuleVersion='3.3.618.0'}
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='ExchangeOnlineManagement';ModuleVersion='2.0.4'}

Connect-ExchangeOnline
```

**Error Message:**

```
 {
      "errorType": "PSRemotingTransportException",
      "errorMessage": "This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.",
      "stackTrace": [
        "at Amazon.Lambda.PowerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost.ExecuteFunction(Stream inputStream, ILambdaContext context)",
        "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
      ],
      "cause": {
        "errorType": "DllNotFoundException",
        "errorMessage": "Unable to load shared library 'libpsrpclient' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibpsrpclient: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
        "stackTrace": [
          "at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManNativeApi.WSManInitialize(Int32 flags, IntPtr& wsManAPIHandle)",
          "at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.WSManClientSessionTransportManager.WSManAPIDataCommon..ctor()"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: With only the error message we can't help you, we also need your code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this, the answer is, you can't!
AWS Lambda PowerShell is PowerShell Core. You cannot currently run ExchangeOnline PowerShell commands in PowerShell Core. Only in Windows Powershell on a Windows system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).